# What damage will an accidental move of /bin do?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, executable

Whilst testing a little bash script I've been writing, a little finger trouble led to a directory name variable not being passed in, resulting in a move command being applied to /* .

/boot was moved first, then /bin. At this point the process stoppped, as the system didn't have access to /bin/mv anymore. I managed to reinstate the two directories, but have had some side-effects.

I found that password checking working for the su command had stopped working, which I fixed by replacing the SetUID permission bit for /bin/su.

I'm concerned that there may be other issues which I'm not aware of, **are there any other executables in /bin that I'll need to fix?**

Comment: `mount` and `umount` are also `setuid` (`find /bin -prem -4111` lists `mount`, `umount`, `su`, `ping`, `ping6` and `fusermount`, but the first two are the most important, I think).

Comment: Sure, if you think that qualifies for an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for SETUID binaries in `/bin`:

```
$ find /bin -perm -4111
/bin/umount
/bin/su
/bin/mount
/bin/ping6
/bin/ping
/bin/fusermount
```

Of these, `mount` and `umount` are the really important ones.